Adding state to JPA entity fields
I’m using Spring Boot with Hibernate and have an entity containing various kinds of fields:
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
  @Id
  private UUID id;

  private Integer width;

  @ManyToOne
  private List<Foo> food;

  @OneToMany
  private Bar bar;

  // etc.
}

Now I want to add state to some/all fields. State is an enum indicating whether the value is either PRESENT, SKIPPED or EMPTY. Thus another column should be added to some/all fields in the DB.
I have tried to create a generic  @Embeddable to wrap the fields:
@Embeddable
public class Stateful<T> {
  T value;

  State state;
}

But this won’t let me set different annotations for the value. What is the best way to achieve this?

No clear what you are asking but sounds like you might want to set some field dynamically before save: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events
